# How to calculate the sum of a particular field of all the documents in a collection in Firestore | Dart

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

```
 return  Container(
        height: 70,
        width: 100,
        color: Colors.white,
        child: StreamBuilder(
            stream: testRef
                .snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                    return CircularProgressIndicator();
              }

                    return Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                            child: Text(
                              "Total is : ",
                            ),
                          ),
                          Text(
                             " " , )
                        ]);
            }));
```

Here is a picture of the Firestore documents
[First Document variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zJ0m.png)
[Second Document variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8iR1T.png)

How can I calculate the sum of the two variables and display it in a Text widget

Comment: RxDart may be a good solution. You can combine streams using it. https://pub.dev/packages/rxdart

Comment: RxDart is very interesting, thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
return  Container(
        height: 70,
        width: 100,
        color: Colors.white,
        child: StreamBuilder(
            stream: testRef
                .snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                    return CircularProgressIndicator();
              }
              var ds = snapshot.data.documents;
              double sum = 0.0;
              for(int i=0; i<ds.length;i++)
                  sum+=(ds[i]['first_number']).toDouble();

              return Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                            child: Text(
                              "Total is : $sum ",
                            ),
                          ),
                          Text(" " , ),
                        ]);
              
            }));
```

Comment: This is a good one but works as long as there's only two documents in the collection, what if there's more than two documents what would be the syntax

Comment: it says type 'bool' is not a subtype of type 'num' of 'other' @Niteesh

Comment: @BinGhaleb sorry, forgot to add an extra layer of bracket , try now

Comment: Works perfectly for two documents if I added a third one the word " Total is : " is duplicated and the number is not added to the sum 

here's a picture of the output

https://ibb.co/rkG7gW6


@Niteesh

Comment: @BinGhaleb you want to add the new ones to the previous sum ?

Comment: @BinGhaleb  mean you want to find the total of all documents ?

Comment: Yes... @Niteesh

Comment: @BinGhaleb and want to print total just once right ?

Comment: It's working perfectly, Thanks for your time. really appreciate it. @Niteesh